# Cancel previous NSOperation?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have methods which may be called too often. When I call the same method for another time I don't need the results from the previous call if it is still not executed. My solution:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperation *callMethodWithParamOperation;

[self callMethodWithParam:param1];
...
[self callMethodWithParam:param2];

- (void)callMethodWithParam:(id)param {

    [self.callMethodWithParamOperation cancel];
    self.callMethodWithParamOperation = ...;
    [operationQueue addOperation:self.callMethodWithParamOperation];
}
```

The problem is there are a lot of methods `callMethodWithParam:` and with my solution I must create a property for each of them. I could create a static variable inside the method but it is worse because I still need to create a variable for each method and additionally I must retain its value manually which may cause memory troubles.

Are there easier ways to implement this behaviour?

Comment: One solution is to create a NSOperationQueue for each type of operation you perform and everytime you call your method you can cancel all the currents operations

Comment: It is not appropriate because I need to perform all the operations in the same order as they called, so I need one queue or I should use a lot of "dependencies" - at least one for each operation.